# What is the equation of a circle passing through the points $(3,1)$ and $(6,4)$ and is tangent to the $y$-axis?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My teacher told me there are two equations. But I cannot understand why this should be true. Can anyone help to go through this?

Comment: Hint: From H.R.'s picture, observe that the centre of the required circle lies on the perpendicular bisector of the two given points.  Think about "tangent to the $y$-axis to formulate a circle, substitute the two points.

Comment: "My teach told me there are two equations." is not a question at all. Please make the body of the question self contained.

Comment: I know the question is already on hold as *off-topic*, but I feel the need to also point out that it is a possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/101986/145141.

Answer (score 3):

**Hints**

$1.$ This picture will help you to imagine better. :)

$2.$ The equations of the circles are

$$\begin{array}{}
\color{green}{\text{Green:}} & (x-3)^2+(y-4)^2=25 \\
\color{red}{\text{Red:}} & (x-15)^2+(y+8)^2=225
\end{array}$$

[image]